# Shading Google Guava with Maven not working for Elasticsarch 2.4.6

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch

I'm using JDK 1.7 and because of that I had to implement Elastic 2.4.6. We also use Richfaces and it uses google Guava 11 as dependency, but Elastic needs Guava 18.
After some research, the best option for me would be shading, I did step by step like it is here: https://www.elastic.co/blog/to-shade-or-not-to-shade, but even after the shading, it still does not work and I get the Exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()
```

I unpacked my jar and the google guava classes are indeed shaded, but it does no work.
Any ideas ?

This is my pom for shading:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.andre</groupId>
<artifactId>elasticsearch-shaded</artifactId>
<version>2.4.6-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>elasticsearch-shaded</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <relocations>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>com.google.common</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>shaded.com.google.common</shadedPattern>
                            </relocation>
                        </relocations>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer" />
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then in my project I just use it as a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.andre</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-shaded</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

All my classes that uses elastic compiles with no problem, but I still get the error that it didn't find the guava class, because it is still using 11 instead of the sahded 18.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Maybe try something like [this blog](https://medium.com/@minyodev/relocating-classes-using-apache-maven-shade-plugin-6957a1a8666d) does. Because you're shading a dependency of dependency, rather than direct dependency.

Comment: @Hitobat I tried that also, same problem happens.
I can't shade the direct dependency(Google Guava) because in my project I don't use it directly, richfaces uses it.... the same way that Elastic uses it,.